# Java 9: What are collection factory methods?

Tags: java, collections, factory, literals, java-9

The arrival of Java 9 brings many new features to Java's Collections API, one of which being collection factory methods.

What are they and how can I implement them properly?

Comment: I somewhat agree, I'll try making the question more specific.

Comment: I could see this being a great canonical duplicate if the question was just "What are Collection Literals and how do I use them?"

Comment: @4castle I just submitted my edit right before you mentioned that, and it seems that we share the same idea.

Comment: @JacobG. - I think you are missing Jim's point.  Instead of tweaking the question to make it "more acceptable", you should >>put<< the answer into the SO Documentation.

Comment: @StephenC I understand, I'll add it tomorrow when I'm not on my phone.  Hopefully I have the privileges to do so.

Comment: It will go through the normal review process, but I see no reasons why it should get rejected.

Comment: @StephenC Well, the reason it should get rejected is that, it is simply not collection literals

Comment: I suggest renaming the question to **"Java 9: What are Collection factory methods?"** according to JEP 269. Collection literals were proposed in JEP 186 and were rejected.

Comment: @AdrianShum - That's wrong.  It should be accepted and then the minor problems should be fixed.  That's the way we do it in the Java Documentation.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I agree, I'll change it right now!

Comment: I've submitted documentation for collection factory methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub><sub>Note 1: To prevent the use of raw-types, I have opted to provide a generic type for each class that I mention below by using `E`, representing an element of a `Collection<E>`.</sub></sub>

<sub><sub>Note 2: This answer is subject to change; please edit this post if a typo has occurred.</sub></sub>

### What are collection factory methods?

A collection factory method in Java is a static method that provides a simple way of initializing an **immutable** `Collection<E>`.

**Being immutable, no elements can be added to, removed from, or modified inside the `Collection<E>` after it is initialized.**

With Java 9, collection factory methods are provided for the following interfaces: `List<E>`, `Set<E>`, and `Map<K, V>`

### What do they improve?

Up until Java 9, there has been no simple, universal method to initialize a `Collection<E>` with initial elements/key-value entries.  Previously, developers were required to initialize them as follows (assuming the generic types `E`, `K`, and `V` have been replaced with `Integer`):

- `List<Integer>`

  - The following method is arguably the simplest to initialize a `List<Integer>` with initial elements, however the result is simply a view of a `List<Integer>`; we are unable to add to or remove from this `List<Integer>`, but we are still able to modify existing elements by using `List#set`.

    - `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`
  - If we wanted our `List<Integer>` to be entirely mutable, then we would have to pass it to the constructor of an `ArrayList<Integer>`, for example:

    - `List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`
- `Set<Integer>`

  - A `Set<Integer>` required more code to initialize with initial elements than a `List<Integer>` does (seeing as a `List<Integer>` is required to initialize a `Set<Integer>` with initial elements), which can be seen below.

    - `Set<Integer> mutableSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`
- `Map<Integer, Integer>`

  - A `Map<Integer, Integer>` is arguably the most complicated to initialize with initial key-value entries; however, there are multiple ways to go about it.

    - One method was to first initialize an empty `Map<Integer, Integer>` and simply call `Map#put` to add key-value entries.
    - Another method was to use an anonymous class with two curly braces, which would still require `Map#put` to be called.

### Why should I use them?

I argue that collection factory methods provide the developer with a concise method of initializing a `List<E>`, `Set<E>`, or `Map<K, V>` with initial elements/key-value entries, which can be seen by the examples below.

### What is the proper syntax to use?

For simplicity, these examples will replace the generic types `E`, `K`, and `V` with `Integer`.

- `List<Integer>`

  - `List<Integer> list = List.of();`

    - Initializes an empty, immutable `List<Integer>`.
  - `List<Integer> list = List.of(1);`

    - Initializes an immutable `List<Integer>` with one element.
  - `List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2);`

    - Initializes an immutable `List<Integer>` with two elements.
  - `List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...);`

    - Initializes an immutable `List<Integer>` with a variable amount of elements.
- `Set<Integer>`

  - `Set<Integer> set = Set.of();`

    - Initializes an empty, immutable `Set<Integer>`.
  - `Set<Integer> set = Set.of(1);`

    - Initializes an immutable `Set<Integer>` with one element.
  - `Set<Integer> set = Set.of(1, 2);`

    - Initializes an immutable `Set<Integer>` with two elements.
  - `Set<Integer> set = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...);`

    - Initializes an immutable `Set<Integer>` with a variable amount of elements.
- `Map<Integer, Integer>`

  - `Map<Integer, Integer> map = Map.of();`

    - Initializes an empty, immutable `Map<Integer, Integer>`.
  - `Map<Integer, Integer> map = Map.of(1, 2);`

    - Initializes an immutable `Map<Integer, Integer>` with one key-value entry.
    - Note that the key is `1` and the value is `2`.
  - `Map<Integer, Integer> map = Map.of(1, 2, 3, 4);`

    - Initializes an immutable `Map<Integer, Integer>` with two key-value entries.
    - Note that the keys are `1` and `3` and the values are `2` and `4`.
  - `Map<Integer, Integer> map = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry(1, 2), Map.entry(3, 4), ...);`

    - Initializes an immutable `Map<Integer, Integer>` with a variable amount of key-value entries.

As you can see, this new method of initialization requires less code than its predecessors.

### Can I use collection factory methods to create mutable objects?

The `Collection<E>` created by collection factory methods are inherently immutable, however we are able to pass them to a constructor of an implementation of the `Collection<E>` to produce a mutable version:

- `List<Integer>`

  - `List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`
- `Set<Integer>`

  - `Set<Integer> mutableSet = new HashSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`
- `Map<Integer, Integer>`

  - `Map<Integer, Integer> mutableMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1, 2, 3, 4));`

Comment: `Map` IS in Collection API.  Collection is more than things implementing `Collection<E>`

Comment: and, I doubt this can be called collection *literal*.  They are just collection factory methods, which allow ease of creating collections **without** collection literals.

Comment: @Jacob I suggest renaming the question to **"Java 9: What are Collection factory methods?"** according to JEP 269. Collection literals were proposed in JEP 186 and were rejected.

Comment: What is the point of saying “(non)empty”? Are you trying to say that the collections are either, empty or not empty? That’s a not a real statement.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!  I have edited the answer to ameliorate the issues.

Comment: The section "How are they implemented" isn't a concern of any users of the API. All the classes mentioned are private, and they are subject to change in future releases.

Comment: @StuartMarks I only listed it because, like me, some developers might be interested in its implementation.  It doesn't hurt to have it, and I'll gladly edit it if a change is made.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw It can be closed if needed, I've already submitted documentation for it :)

Comment: So now we can do `Set<Integer> mutableSet = new HashSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));` and saved 7 characters, what an improvement /s.

Also what use is unmodifiable map? Lazy developers not needing to create a proper Class or better Enum / EnumSet?

This will just cause `UnsupportedOperationException` to enter top 10 Java exceptions in production code.

Comment: The internal implementations of these classes have changed in Java 11, so the early section on implementation details is now obsolete.

Comment: @StuartMarks Thanks for letting me know; I'll remove it!